# Open problems in "Algebraic geometry by robin hartshorne"

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, open-problems

Hi,

Is there a list of which of the open problems in algebraic geometry by robin hartshorne are still open ?
(I searched the internet and didn't find one)

Thanks from advanced,
Matan Fattal

Comment: Do you mean open problems mentioned in Hartshorne's book or conjectures that he made?

Comment: problems mentioned in hartshornes book (the ** excercises)

Comment: I think all of them are still open.

Comment: do you know of any refernce ?

Comment: No, but you can look up relevant words on Google Scholar.  Hartshorne has said that his entire mathematical career was structured around trying to prove the set-theoretic intersection conjecture (I.2.17d), and it still seems to be open.  The ArXiv gets "proofs" of the Jacobian conjecture (I.3.19d) reasonably often.  If it were proved, we wouldn't see that much activity.  Also, if either were solved, I imagine people would talk.  Are there other problems that I missed?

Comment: Thank you very much. First time using this site and it's amazing. you helped me alot.

Comment: @Matan Fattal This is the list of open problems http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0040938379900302